# At the time of Gnome desktop installation ubuntu software center removed, unable to install anymore

Tags: software-center, dpkg, python-2.7

At the time of Gnome desktop installation, it has removed all the dependencies of sso login python and ubuntu software center.

I've tried to rebuilt them using sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade with -f, but no result.

Thanks and Regards
Utpal

Comment: Try  re-installing "sudo apt-get install software-centre".  If you get any error messages edit your question and paste the error messages in there.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install software-center`

If python is also removed from your system, It is difficult to recover